# help in adapting a monster from a short story to 5E

Tags: dnd-5e, monster-design

This is the 'Big Bad' of the short story Undefiled, written by James M. Ward for the collection Tales of Ravenloft. From what I've inquired the creature was created by Ward specifically for the story.

I'm looking for how to work out appropriate 5E statistics for the monster in  question (the author calls it a Coraltan) based on its actions, abilities and description as depicted in the story.

This 'Coraltan' is a corporeal undead, whose body is described as "desiccated and worm-infested". However it is able to take on the appearance of a living humanoid (in this story it poses as a city's spiritual leader), presumably through some form of illusion magic such as *disguise self*.

In the act of preforming what appear to be temple services, this being preformed magic that healed two people badly wounded and weakened by the attack of a vampire, though no specific divine spells as you would find in the Player's Handbook were mentioned by name.

Near the end of the story it also used a form of mind-influencing magic to ensure any humans in its 'flock' would not enter its temple quarters and possibly discover its true nature.

Finally, the monster in question seems to 'feed' on the energy (yes, I know you're going to complain how vague that sounds but it's as specific as I know how to say it) of its human followers in the act of preforming temple services. Rather than drain an single human dry, it seems to absorb a little bit of energy each from individuals in a large crowd, also it appears capable of feeding on a living being's energy without having to reach out and physically touch its victim (again, as specific as I know how to say it).

I would suggest a CR of at least 10, possibly closer to 15.

**What source material (published monsters, class features...) would provide most of the features I cited from the story**? (undead, dessicated / worm-infested, take shape of living humanoid, healing and mind control magic, drains life energy) **Ideally an example monster would provide most of these, have the appropriate CR already, and allow for the addition of the others without much mechanical rebalancing.**

Comment: Have you looked for an existing monster you could simply reskin? I can think of one well known monster that would fit this description with a little work already.

Comment: Can you clarify what the actual ask is here? Is this a need for existing mechanics you can use with a monster?  If so, is the list: a mechanic for "feed on people without touching" (what does that entail specifically), and method of illusion disguise?

Comment: @PurpleMonkey- what monster are you referring to?

Comment: @GcL- I'm looking for a way to adapt the creature I've described to existing 5E mechanics. As for how to feed without touching, well I mean a way to take or maybe absorb life from someone without, well, walking up to and touching them, not sure how to be more specific than that.

Comment: It would be best  if you could use the DMG and MM to write up a draft of the monster. Then we can provide you some relevant/useful feedback.

Comment: I could also provide a list of minsters to borrow from or quickly stat up a block. But the info provided is insufficient for the latter. Especially knowing the target CR would be important.

Comment: The part of handling positive energy seems opinion based the way it is stated. Also, it is beyond the scope of the question. Asking for monsters that have the qualities you listed seems like a good idea. Like what monsters have one or more of the following qualities: undead, disguise self, drain life, ... To make the question more concise you should probably take out some of the additional questions. Saying that the life drain part is especially important for the examples is a possibility, though. If you want stats, people can probably help also, but you need to be clear on the style first.

Comment: You don't need a higher CR to be able to intimidate someone, especially someone with pronounced weaknesses, like a vampire. You should choose a CR based on its position in your story.

Comment: Unfortunately, the stack really isn't set up for 'homebrew this for me'. If that's the help you're looking for, you may do better on a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) or in our very own [chat].

Comment: @kingofpanes If you are still interested in this question, you could give it another shot and edit it. See this meta post for a detailed discussion: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10007/can-this-question-about-homebrewing-potentially-be-reopened/10009?noredirect=1#comment34431_10009